# Prevent complete charging?

Tags: battery, battery-life, charging

I'm looking for a way to prevent my phone from completely charging every time it is connected to my computer. I want to reduce the battery's capacity loss, as it is non-replaceable, and it seems to me that keeping the maximum charge at around 50% to 60% would be ideal. This chart, from [this site](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries), suggests that the benefit would be significant.

```
Capacity at    Discharge
full charge    cycles

100%           300 – 500
90%            600 – 1,000
70%            1,200 – 2,000
50%            2,400 – 4,000
```

Comment: Surely you'll be charging it more often if you don't charge it fully?

Comment: I charge when I get the chance, and my currently battery never drops below 60%.

Comment: That table refers to storage, not use; you may want Table 4 instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Table 4 actually communicates my point better.

Comment: While, yes, charging to 50-60% max would increase the recharge cycles, you would also need to recharge many, many more times, making this method ineffective.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos I think that's why they call it "charge cycles", a full cycle = 100% on the scale. More full cycles by charging only to 60%, means much longer battery life.

Answer (score 1):

The only potential solution would be to find a way to current-limit the cable so that the phone would have to run off battery. You cannot simply disconnect Vcc and Ground pins, as the USB standard requires the presence of those electrical connections before D+ and D- pins are permitted to be energized. Running off battery like that would just increase your charge cycles, causing the wear you want to avoid.

As far as apps, there is no way to programmatically control the battery charging subsystem in this way; BatteryManager outputs information but does not accept inputs from user apps.

Answer (score 1):

[SMART PLUG](https://wiki.microduino.cc/index.php?title=Open_Source_Smart_Power_Plug) is an intelligent outlet that can measure power usage and provide basic power management to attached appliances via the standard electrical outlet.

You can buy [this WiFi PLUG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00M5FKN0U) or [build your own](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-alternative-to-commercial-smart-power-sockets/). Plugs are available that [support USB Charging](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Upgraded-Version-Letouch%C2%AE-Charging-Technology-Red/dp/B011UAP1ZW). You can find more plugs of your choice in the market.

- Now every time you charge your device charge it using this plug. There are many alternatives to the plug I have provided in link. Many of the plugs have dedicated [Control apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dlink.mydlinkmyhome&hl=en) for Android and iPhone built for them.
- After this you can configure your [Tasker app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) to run the Control app whenever there is 50%(whatever you like) charge complete to just turn off the plug.

References:

- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/best-smart-plugs/
- https://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/XBee_Smart_Plug
- https://gigaom.com/2014/02/18/in-praise-of-the-humble-smart-plug-are-outlets-the-gateway-for-the-internet-of-things/

Comment: yes, there are plugs that [support USB Charging](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Upgraded-Version-Letouch%C2%AE-Charging-Technology-Red/dp/B011UAP1ZW). You can find more of your choice on the internet.

Answer (score -1):

Currently the batteries no longer have this limitation in relation to charges, they can work with loads at any level, from 1% to 100% without any problems.
However it is recommended to never leave download completely, because each one complete discharge battery life cycle is lost.

Comment: Perhaps you missed OP's concern elaborated in the linked site in question and further amplified in comments. If you didn't and have sources to validate your answer, kindly link them- else the answer could be downvoted and eventually removed, which is not a welcome a new user would like to get